# Keyboard Shortcuts no longer working on ALL Delphi versions on this Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, delphi

One of my favorite Delphi IDE keyboard shortcuts is the handy <kbd>Ctrl-K-I</kbd>, that let's me indent a block of code that contains existing indents, and which indents the selected set to the right, while keeping all lines in the block at their same relative indent.

I was using this shortcut, but I apparently hit a wrong key on the keyboard.  Suddenly I found that ALL keyboard shortcuts had stopped working -- in ALL versions of Delphi on this Windows 10 PC.

Windows shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> still work, and GExperts shortcuts also still work, but the Delphi key mapping shortcuts in the IDEs no longer work.

I would think this would be some sort of Windows connection used between all Delphi IDEs and Windows, but I haven't found anything to fix this yet.

Any clues?

Comment: There is no keystroke in any Delphi version that will affect any other installed version of Delphi. All IDE configuration is only for the currently active version of the IDE (the one you're working in).

Comment: What is your current keyboard mapping (Tools->Options->User Unterface->Keyboard Mapping)? What happens when you select a block of code and use Ctrl+Shift+I to indent and Ctrl+Shift+U to unindent?

Comment: If keyboard shortcuts stopped working in all installed Delphi versions at once then the cause might not be in Delphi but some other program that is stealing the said shortcuts as it might have registered same shortcuts systemwide. When dealing with systemwide shortcuts you need to know that first program that registers them as systemwide ha access to them. All programs that try to register same shortcuts later will not be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that some other application catch the keyboard interruption at the same time. In my case it was video card Radeon Software. I just navigate to Radeon Software -> Settings -> ShortCuts tab and disable all shortcuts by switch button. After that it starts working in Delphi IDE without restart.